# What is the proper way of using pd.concat with .copy() for getting copy (not a reference) as a result?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate data frames and get the result as an independent copy (I do not want that the resulting data frame to be referenced of source data frames).

I have code:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'var_1': [1,2,3], 'var_2': [4,5,6]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'s1': [1,2,3], 's2': [4,5,6]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
df4 = pd.concat([df1.copy(),df2.copy()], axis=1)
df5 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).copy()
```

As I understand to get copy (and not just a reference) I need to use `.copy()`. In my example above I am using it in two ways (`df4` and `df5`).

**Question:** Which and **why** is a right way to use `.copy()` with `pd.concat` from any of my example or maybe even other?

Comment: This should be the right way - ```df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)```, one reason I can think of is that `pd.concat` has an optional parameter called `copy` which is defaulted to `True`, so I guess internally, the `concat` function does create a copy of the data frames it needs to concat, so you wouldn't have to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

[pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) always return an independent dataframe, so the most memory-efficient in terms of memory is `df3`, you can still set `copy` parameter to `False` and the result is a new dataframe.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, copy=False)
df3['var_1'] = False
print(df1.var_1) # this is not modified

# 0    1
# 1    2
# 2    3
```